# x:Name not working if element wrapped in UserControl's content (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, wrapper, code-behind

**Situation:**

I have a "wrapper panel" `UserControl` like this (namespaces and visual details removed for brevity):

```
<UserControl ...>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="integratedPanelContent" Margin="5" /> 
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then in the Code-behind I have registered a dependency property

```
public FrameworkElement PanelContent
{
    get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(PanelContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PanelContentProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty PanelContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("PanelContent", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(MyWrapperPanel),
      new PropertyMetadata(null, OnPanelContentChanged));

private static void OnPanelContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MyWrapperPanel)d).OnSetContentChanged(e);
}

protected virtual void OnSetContentChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (PanelContent != null)
        integratedPanelContent.Content = PanelContent;
}
```

Now I can wrap any content into my control:

```
<my:MyWrapperPanel x:Name="myWrap">
    <my:MyWrapperPanel.PanelContent>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbxNothing" Text="Nothing" />
    </my:MyWrapperPanel.PanelContent>
</my:MyWrapperPanel>
```

**Description of the problem:**

Whenever I try to use the reference tbxNothing in codebehind, the system throws `NullReferenceException` because tbxNothing, although as a reference exists, does not point to the TextBlock defined in XAML, but is `null`.

**Possible (but inconvenient) workaround:**

There is a workaround where I remove `x:Name` from the TextBlock, and then I explicitely define private TextBlock called `tbxNothing`. Then in the `OnNavigatedTo` event handler I assign the value the following way:

```
tbxNothing = myWrap.PanelContent as TextBlock;
```

This works but is not a right way to do it, because if a content is a stackpanel that contains wanted controls, I'd have to traverse the tree to find what I need, which is extremely inconvenient.

**Question:**

Why is the textblock no longer visible when wrapped in a User control (the way described), and how to get it by its x:Name in code-behind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your panel content is falling between two stools. On the one hand the content with the name "tbxNothing" is create in the namescope of the main page.  However its not added to the object tree at that point.  On the other hand the MyWrapperPanel being a UserControl has its own namescope and its into the object tree below this that the item with then name "tbxNothing" is added.  `FindName` on the main page won't find anything inside the MyWrapperPanel because it has its own namescope and `FindName` on the MyWrapperPanel won't find "tbxNothing" because it doesn't exist in its namescope (being actually created in the main page).

The answer is don't use a `UserControl` as a basis for `MyWrapperPanel`.  Instead create a Silverlight Template Control.  Modify the base class it inherits from to `ContentControl` and tweak its default template to include a `ContentPresenter`.  Should look something like this:-

```
public class MyWrapperPanel : ContentControl
{
    public MyWrapperPanel ()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyWrapperPanel );
    }
}
```

then in themes/generic.xaml the style can look like this:-

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyWrapperPanel">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyWrapperPanel">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Your main page xaml would look like:-

```
<my:MyWrapperPanel x:Name="myWrap">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbxNothing" Text="Nothing" />
</my:MyWrapperPanel>
```

Note that deriving from `ContentControl` gives you a `Content` property which the `ContentPresenter` auto-magically wires to.

Comment: I am definitely gonna try this, but I am unsure about one thing. Some elements of the MyWrapperPanel are interactive, so I have previously put some event handlers into my UserControl's code-behind. If I define the elements through the template, how can I reach specific elements from the template to perform custom logic? Would specifying x:Name on template elements be visible in control's codebehind through FindName() or is there a better way to achieve custom logic on template defined elements?

Comment: @kornelijepetak: Yes you can use `x:Name` in the template however from code within the custom templated control they are accessed using the `GetTemplateChild` protected method.  `FindName` will now work on the namescope of the containing `UserControl` thats why this approach fixes your initial problem.

Comment: but do I need to use FindName() in main page or can I access the TextBlock by using tbxNothing reference?

Comment: @kornelijepetak: If you open the definition of `InitialiseComponent` you will see that ulitmately the `tbxNothing` field (what you are calling a "reference") is assigned by auto generated code using `FindName`.  The whole point of this approach is to place the new custom control and all is "Content" controls (not the template just the controls placed in the `ContentPresenter`) all in the same namescope.  Hence `FindName` will find "tbxNothing" and therefore also the `tbxNothing` field will have a value rather than be null.

Comment: I have finally tried this solution and it works. Marking as answer.